# django 1.7 makemigrations recreating 0001_initial.py

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-migrations

In my current work situation I'm having a simple but odd error with Django.

Whenever I use the command:

`./manage.py makemigrations app1`

It recreates the `0001_initial.py` file every time it runs. And it's not checking weither there are older migration files.

There are - in fact - 31 older migration files. All made with Django 1.7. Not South.

Does anyone have any idea where to search?

If extra info in needed, please ask and I will provide :)

Comment: Is the content of `0001_initial.py` the same every time? What is it generating?

Comment: @schillingt As far as I'm concerned it just generates a correct migration file. It just ditches the previous migration files.. http://pastebin.com/9hfDtEQX

Comment: Is this after you also `migrate` the migrations?

Comment: And... I found that it actually WERE SOUTH MIGRATIONS! I had to look at my second migration to see that it imported the south library. Guess I'll have to look up and see what to make of this. Starting with getting the original initial.py from the GIT repository :)